# Can I attach a CloudWatch event rule to a 'built-in target' via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform

The goal here is to create scheduled snapshots of EBS volumes. Looking at Terraform's documentation for [`aws_cloudwatch_event_target`](http://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_target.html) it doesn't seem possible, but I could be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloudwatch Events built-in targets just seem to require an input parameter as well as the ARN that is shown for adding a message to an SNS queue in the example for [`aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html) or sending to a Kinesis stream in [`aws_cloudwatch_event_target`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_target.html).

So we should just be able to do something like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "ebs_vol_a" {
  target_id = "ebs_vol_a"
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.snap_ebs.name}"
  arn = "arn:aws:automation:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:action/EBSCreateSnapshot/EBSCreateSnapshot_ebs_vol_a"
  input = "\"arn:aws:ec2:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:volume/vol-${var.ebs_vol_a_id}\""
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "snap_ebs" {
  name = "snap-ebs-volumes"
  description = "Snapshot EBS volumes"
  schedule_expression = "rate(6 hours)"
}
```

I haven't yet tested this but it *should* work. Obviously you probably want to get the EBS volume IDs from the resource you created them but that's beyond the scope of the question. I've also guessed at the ARN after creating a rule in the AWS console and then looking at the output of `aws events list-targets-by-rule` where it seems to add the rule name to the ARN of the target but that may not always be true/necessary.

Comment: So close! I had to manually select the role for the built-in targets

Comment: @ds011591 Can you elaborate? Were you able to create this all in Terraform?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working entirely in terraform by tweaking [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079499/2171020) provided by [D Swartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025644/d-swartz). I had to modify the `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` resource in a few ways:

1. The `arn` field needs to point to the `target/create-snapshot` event instead of the `action/EBSCreateSnapshot` automation action.
2. The `input` field needs to be set to the desired volume's `id` rather than its `arn`.
3. The `role_arn` needs to be set to the `arn` of the `aws_iam_role` that will be running the event.

The updated `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` resource looks like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "example_event_target" {
  target_id = "example"
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.snapshot_example.name}"
  arn = "arn:aws:events:${var.aws_region}:${var.account_id}:target/create-snapshot"
  input = "${jsonencode("${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}")}"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.snapshot_permissions.arn}"
}
```

Full code snippet below:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "snapshot_example" {
  name = "example-snapshot-volumes"
  description = "Snapshot EBS volumes"
  schedule_expression = "rate(24 hours)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "example_event_target" {
  target_id = "example"
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.snapshot_example.name}"
  arn = "arn:aws:events:${var.aws_region}:${var.account_id}:target/create-snapshot"
  input = "${jsonencode("${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}")}"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.snapshot_permissions.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "snapshot_permissions" {
  name = "example"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "automation.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "snapshot_policy" {
  name        = "example-snapshot-policy"
  description = "grant ebs snapshot permissions to cloudwatch event rule"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "snapshot_policy_attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.snapshot_permissions.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.snapshot_policy.arn}"
}
```

**edit:** I'm not entirely clear if this is directly supported by AWS or not - based on [their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html) it seems like this may not be an intended feature:

> Creating rules with built-in targets is supported only in the AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer was enough to get everything except for the IAM permissions on the event targets (i.e. go into the console, edit the rule, and in "Step 2", for the "AWS Permissions" section, create a new role, etc). To get this working in terraform, I just added a few resources:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "snapshot_example" {
  name = "example-snapshot-volumes"
  description = "Snapshot EBS volumes"
  schedule_expression = "rate(24 hours)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "example_event_target" {
  target_id = "example"
  rule = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.snapshot_example.name}"
  arn = "arn:aws:automation:${var.aws_region}:${var.account_id}:action/EBSCreateSnapshot/EBSCreateSnapshot_example-snapshot-volumes"
  input = "${jsonencode("arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:${var.account_id}:volume/${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}")}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "snapshot_permissions" {
  name = "example"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "automation.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "snapshot_policy" {
    name        = "example-snapshot-policy"
    description = "grant ebs snapshot permissions to cloudwatch event rule"
    policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "snapshot_policy_attach" {
    role       = "${aws_iam_role.snapshot_permissions.name}"
    policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.snapshot_policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about how this works, the role isn't actually used here. Does the fact that the name matches the target_id matter? I feel like you need to use the `role_arn` attribute in the `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`

Comment: It's been awhile, but I think the idea is to create a "sevice role". Instead of creating a role for the target (which just ties the event to the action), we're creating a role for the "principal", or the entity that is actually running the action.
The target event rule isn't running the service, it's just kicking it off. It's the "automation.amazonaws.com" service that id getting kicked off, so it is what needs the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution which is compatible with AWS CloudWatch Rules and Amazon EventBridge:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "volume_snapshot_rule" {
  name                = "ebs-volume-snapshot"
  description         = "Create an EBS volume snapshot every 6 hours"
  schedule_expression = "rate(6 hours)"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "volume_snapshot_target" {
  target_id = "ebs-volume-snapshot-target"
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.volume_snapshot_rule.name
  arn       = "arn:aws:events:eu-central-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:target/create-snapshot"
  role_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/create-ebs-snapshot"
  input     = "\"${aws_ebs_volume.storage.id}\""
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

And for the IAM role

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "create_ebs_snapshot" {
  name = "create-ebs-snapshot"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "events.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })

  inline_policy {
    name = "policy"

    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Action   = ["ec2:CreateSnapshot"]
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Resource = "*"
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}
```